# HTTP header and its HTTP value

Tags: rest, http-headers

[API Integration with localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYv1C.jpg)

What is the http header and http values to be entered here for the connection with the localhost ?

Comment: Please let us know exactly what error message you've got?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever headers and values you have designed your server side code to require.

The software you are using gives you the option to add additional HTTP headers. There's no requirement that you use that option.

Comment: Whenever i'm trying to connect it says connection refused.

Comment: That would be because you aren't running an HTTP server on `localhost` on port `15672`. It has nothing to do with the HTTP headers. (You might be using a third party hosted web service to do your testing, in which case `localhost` will be resolved from *their* computer, not yours).